# How to apply a custom control template in the Tabcontrol control in silverlight 5

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, listbox, mvvm-light

I have a page where I have a listbox which displays time for a given date. As per the image the top part displays today's data but in the lower half I have a requirement that if some specific date is selected then the Tabcontrol should take the dates(week) dynamically and display those days of the week in the header for the tabcontrol. Corresponding to each tabs the content should have listboxes with same controltemplate but different data. I am not able to put the listbox inside the content part of the listbox.

### ListBox :

[image]

Comment: Please take the time to edit you question: What is the actual problem? Do you struggle with displaying dates dynamically? What do you mean by "put the listbox inside the content part of the listbox"? Do you have a snippet of xaml that is not doing what you expect?

Comment: I am not able to set the content template(dynamically) inside a ListBox.